# How to prove $\varphi(n)=-\log \mathbb{E}[\exp(-nX)]$ is subadditive

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions

Let be $X$ a positive random variable. I would like to prove that the function $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to [0,+\infty]$ defined by 
$\varphi(n)=-\log \mathbb{E}[\exp(-nX)]$
satisfies $\varphi(m+n)\leq \varphi(n)+\varphi(m)$.

I tried Hölder and Jensen inequalities but I got only a weak result 
that $\varphi(n)\leq n\varphi(1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a consequence of the following:

> **Coupling inequality:** Let $u$ and $v$ be nonincreasing (nonnegative) functions. Then, 
>   $$
> \mathrm E(u(X)v(X))\geqslant \mathrm E(u(X))\mathrm E(v(X)).
> $$

*Proof:* Let $w(x,y)=(u(x)-u(y))(v(x)-v(y))$. Then, $w(x,y)\geqslant0$ for every $x$ and $y$. Let $Y$ denote a random variable independent on $X$ and with the same distribution. Expanding $w$ in the inequality $\mathrm E(w(X,Y))\geqslant0$, one gets
$$
\mathrm E(u(X)v(X))-\mathrm E(u(X)v(Y))-\mathrm E(u(Y)v(X))+\mathrm E(u(Y)v(Y))\geqslant0.
$$
The common value of the first and fourth terms is $\mathrm E(u(X)v(X))$. The common value of the second and third terms is $\mathrm E(u(X))\mathrm E(v(X))$. *End of the proof.*

**Application:** Consider the functions $u:x\mapsto\mathrm e^{-nx}$ and  $v:x\mapsto\mathrm e^{-mx}$.

Comment: It is awesome to get beyond a beautiful answer a new "technique". Thanks a lot Didier Piau for this post and the detailed explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the kind words.